# ng serve compiler choking on prototype functions

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps

I have a google map portion of my web app where I'm using:

```
SitePanel.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
```

And I'm adding some additional `.prototype.functions` like so:

```
SitePanel.prototype.getBounds = function() {
    return new google.maps.LatLngBounds(this.position, this.position); 
};
```

But the `ng serve` compiler is choking on the .prototype.myNewFuction addition with this message:

```
ERROR in src/app/mapview/mapview.component.ts(85,23): error TS2339: Property 'getBounds' does not exist on type 'OverlayView'.
```

Is there a way to type the `getBounds` function I'm adding so that the compiler won't choke on it? (or possibly some other way to approach it?)

Comment: I realize this is related to TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem and get the error to go away by adding 'as any' to the end of the following line:

```
SitePanel.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView() as any;
```